# SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflows

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-activity

Is there a way to set a field with [Today] date and not have it change once it is set.

Thanks
Kim

Comment: Any reason why you cannot just retreive the value from the  OOTB "Created" field? That field will contain the exact time the list item was created

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this question in [another thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65614/sharepoint-designer-workflow-set-field/65630#65630).

In general, you have to check if this field is empty before setting a value to it.

However, it is impossiple to check if a Date field is empty and you have to set value of your Date field to a String variable and then you can check if this String variable is empty.

Hope this approach could be used in your case. If so, please, don't forget to upvote and mark as answer :-).

Comment: Could you give me an example of setting the Data Value to a string?  Would my step be:  If Status = Setup, set Date to Today, then set the variable.  Not sure what to do after that to check.  I can get it to work using a hidden field, but I'd really hate to have to create another field.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the field of a List Item in Workflow by using **Update List Item** action and setting the date column to Current Date

However permissions on columns are not permissible in SharePoint, what you can do is Hide this date column from the List/Library Forms by going into

> List Settings -> Advance Settings -> Allow management of Content Type
>   = Yes

Now,

> Back to list settings -> Under Content Types -> click Item -> click
>   the date column -> check Hidden

This will hide the column from been updated by forms...

Comment: If I hide the Date field can I have a Text field that is updated when the date is set showing the date? I want the date to show so they user will know when the date is set.  What I ended up doing is creating a Y/N field set to Y, update the date field then set the Y/N field to N and hid the Y/N field.

Comment: Do you have InfoPath forms available? It will be easier if you modify the form in InfoPath.. you will need Enterprise SharePoint for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date field in your list and assign it a workflow that will run at item create or change, and check field is empty with if statement then set it with workflow comment 'Update List Item'. You can give it the Today value.