# How to fix [today] and [now] in a list

Tags: list, calculated-column

I have the following issue: we use a SP list to send information through the steps of the process. On each step somebody adds information into the list, next person receives it, adds his own part of information and it goes to the next step and so on. We need to see the date and time when each step was done. For first and last step we see it by columns "created" and "modified" for intermediate steps we created the calculated column with following formula:

```
=IF([Column1]="Yes";TEXT(TODAY();"dd/mm/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(NOW.TIME();"h:mm");"")
```

Problem is that with every new information added into the row the date&time are updated.
How can I fix the date&time that it keeps only the date&time of the moment when somebody added the information in the exact column which I placed in the formula. Maybe it is possible with SP designer?

I found the following answer on a similar question for workflow but don't understand how I can apply it for a List:
[SharePoint Designer Workflow, set field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65614/sharepoint-designer-workflow-set-field)

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

Workflow try
when a person chooses "Yes" in the Status column that in column "Date & Time" appears current date and time and that this time would not be changed if somebody updates the information in the string. 
[image]

EDIT 2
[image]

EDIT 3

Finally it works this way, with the additional settings in "Date & Time" - default value "01/01/2014 0:00:00"
[image]

EDIT 4

Solution

"Date & Time" is the text fild with default value 1
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you shouldn't use a calculated column at all:

It would probably be easiest to use the workflow to set the field value when that intermediate step is complete as is sort-of suggested in your link; to get it working in your situation you need to make the column you're using as a calculated one now a date or text type, then make a workflow or add a new step to a workflow that occurs whenever an item is modified to check for your [Column1]="Yes" then perform the set a field's value action to the current date/time.

Alternatively, you could make whatever form the user in the intermediate step is using set that date value directly when they submit their information.

EDIT: I almost forgot -- make sure you only allow the workflow to set the date for your new column when an item is edited and [Column1]="Yes" AND the column that holds the date it was approved is empty, otherwise the date will always be updated every time the item is edited after [Column1]="Yes"

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Unfortunately I have never used the SP Designer before and now have the following issue: SPD doesn't start the workflow creation at all. I found a lot of videos with different possibilities to start it, but no any works. When I etnry the name and press ok nothing happened.  I have a full control and here is no message with the mistake. Maybe I should make some additional settings? Should I create the separate question for it?

Comment: To set the starting conditions for a workflow, navigate to the list you want the workflow to act on, then select the workflow. You'll see a box called 'Start Options' and you want to check Start workflow automatically when an item is created. Here is a an office article on creating workflows in SPD 2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx

Comment: Could you please look on the workflow which I created. Is it correct? (added pic in the question).On a moment I can't publish it because of permition for workflow, but want to know if it is right or not. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you should start by setting your workflow variable to 'Today' or the Current Item: Modified -- then if your conditions are true set your date/time field to the workflow variable value. The way yours is written will not alter a field in your list item. Additionally, your condition should check the Status1 field and the 'Date & Time 1' field (not the workflow variable).

Comment: Could you please look one more time on the workflow. The idea is correct now? I just can't assigne the check "empty" for Current Item "Date and Time". But it is possible to Variables like in the example http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65614/sharepoint-designer-workflow-set-field

Comment: On the last line, switch the order of assignment -- you want to set 'Current Item: Date and Time" to 'Variable: Date'

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally it works as it showen on the pic EDIT 3. But doesn't show the time, just date (time is 00.00). How it can be solve? Can't find any solution in internet (

Comment: Try setting your Variable: Date to Current Item: Modified instead of Today -- your "Set Date and Time..." line should also be nested underneath the if statement like in the picture for edit 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15997/discussion-between-john-o-and-galina).